# Using dropdownlists to pull data from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, html, excel, html-select

Is there a way that I can use an excel spreadsheet that would then feed into my html / c# program. I have as many as 10 dropdownlists(DDL) that all have different values(example: {Ram [8, 16, 32, 64]} and another being {City[HSV, DAL, SLC, DNV]}, hard-coded into them in the html layer. Those DDL's names and values represent data that is in an excel spreadsheet. I need to write code that pulls certain data from the spreadsheet if and only if that particular value was selected within the DDL. ALL of the things I have tried looking through try to get me to import the spreadsheet and use it like a spreadsheet inside a panel or something. I need to have a way that lets me tinker with it more like a database. I need to be able to write functions/statements that operate like SQL Queries. Thank you for taking the time to read this and your attempt at helping me out.

HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Find.aspx.cs" Inherits="VirginiaCollege.Find" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="None">
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Select what type of user you are..."></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">                
            <asp:ListItem>IT Admin</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Executive Management</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Academic Director</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Teachers</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Students</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>


        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btSubmitUserType" runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" Text="Submit Selection" BackColor="#CCCCCC" OnClick="btSubmitUserType_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />            


    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel6" runat="server" Visible="false" >

        <asp:Label ID="lblEnterPsWrd" runat="server" Text="Please enter the password"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" placeholder="Password" >    </asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Password = Admin"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitUserTypePsWrd" runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" Text="Submit Password" BackColor="#CCCCCC" OnClick="btSubmitUserTypePsWrd_Click" />



    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel7" runat="server" Visible="false" >

        <asp:Label ID="lblEnterPsWrd2" runat="server" Text="Please enter the password"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword2" runat="server" placeholder="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Password = Director"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitUserTypePsWrd2" runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" Text="Submit Password" BackColor="#CCCCCC" OnClick="btSubmitUserTypePsWrd2_Click" />



    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel8" runat="server" Visible="false" >

        <asp:Label ID="lblEnterPsWrd3" runat="server" Text="Please enter the password"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword3" runat="server" placeholder="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Password = Student"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitUserTypePsWrd3" runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" Text="Submit Password" BackColor="#CCCCCC" OnClick="btSubmitUserTypePsWrd3_Click" />



    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="false">

        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCity" runat="server" Text="City" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbComputerType" runat="server" Text="Computer Type" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDepartment" runat="server" Text="Department" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRoomNumber" runat="server" Text="Room Number" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbComputerPosition" runat="server" Text="Computer Postition" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbGraphicsCard" runat="server" Text="Graphics Card" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRAM" runat="server" Text="RAM" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbProgram" runat="server" Text="Program" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbInstallDate" runat="server" Text="Install Date" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbExperationDate" runat="server" Text="Experation Date" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />


        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit Search Criteria" />


    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Visible="false">


        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbComputerType2" runat="server" Text="Computer Type" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDepartment2" runat="server" Text="Department" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRoomNumber2" runat="server" Text="Room Number" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbGraphicsCard2" runat="server" Text="Graphics Card" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRAM2" runat="server" Text="RAM" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbProgram2" runat="server" Text="Program" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Submit Search Criteria" />

    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" Visible="false">

        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbComputerType3" runat="server" Text="Computer Type" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbGraphicsCard3" runat="server" Text="Department" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRAM3" runat="server" Text="Room Number" />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbProgram3" runat="server" Text="Graphics Card" />
        <br />


        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="Submit Search Criteria" />

    </asp:Panel>




    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" Visible="false" HorizontalAlign="Left">

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select City..." Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>HSV</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>DAL</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select Computer Type" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlComputerType" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>CSTU</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>CAD</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Staff</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Select Department" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>3D Imaging</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Accounting</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Business</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Recruiting</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Management</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Teaching</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Select Room Number" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoomNumber" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>32</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>33</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>34</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>36</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>37</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>38</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Select Computer Position" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlComputerPosition" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>32</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>33</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>34</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>36</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>37</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>38</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>39</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Select Graphics Card" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGraphicsCard" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>Dell Nvidia Tesla K40 GPU Computing Processor</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Dell 6 GB Nvidia Tesla K20X GPU Computing Processor</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Dell 2 GB Nvidia Quadro K620 Graphics Card</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Nvidia Quadro K6000 SDI I/O</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>VisionTek CryoVenom R9 290</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Nvidia GeForce GTX 780</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>AMD Radeon R9 295X2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>AMD Radeon R9 290</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>MSI R9 280X Gaming 3G</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Select RAM" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRAM" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>32</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>64</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>128</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Select Program" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgram" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>Xara Photo & Graphic 2013</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Real-time 3D Character</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Autodesk Inventor</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Autodesk AutoCAD 2015</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Autodesk AutoCAD 2014</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Autodesk AutoCAD 2013</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Autodesk AutoCAD 2012</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Autodesk AutoCAD 2011</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Autodesk AutoCAD 2010</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>QuickBooks 2017</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>QuickBooks !=2017</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visual Studio 2015</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visual Studio 2016</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visual Studio 2017</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visual Studio 2013</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visual Studio 2012</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visual Studio 2011</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visual Studio 2010</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visual Studio 2009</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visual Studio 2014</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Office suite</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Select Software Install Date" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSoftInstalDate" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>JUN 2009</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>MAY 2010</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>JUN 2011</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>DEC 2012</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>DEC 2013</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>JAN 2014</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>JAN 2015</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>FEB 2015</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>JUL 2016</asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Select Software Expire Date" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSoftExpDate" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:ListItem>DEC 2013</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>DEC 2014</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>MAY 2015</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>DEC 2015</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>JAN 2016</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>JAN 2017</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>NOV 2018</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>DEC 2018</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>DEC 2019</asp:ListItem>


        </asp:DropDownList>



    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel40" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Panel>

    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList20" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel50" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Panel>














</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace VirginiaCollege
{
public partial class Find : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btSubmitUserType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "IT Admin" )
        {
            Panel6.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Executive Management" )
        {
            Panel6.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Academic Director")
        {
            Panel7.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Teachers")
        {
            Panel8.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Students")
        {
            Panel8.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
        }

    }

    protected void btSubmitUserTypePsWrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbPassword.Text == "Admin")
        {
            Panel2.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
            Panel6.Visible = false;
        }           

    }

    protected void btSubmitUserTypePsWrd2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbPassword2.Text == "Director")
        {
            Panel3.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
            Panel7.Visible = false;
        }

    }

    protected void btSubmitUserTypePsWrd3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbPassword3.Text == "Student")
        {
            Panel4.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
            Panel8.Visible = false;
        }

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbCity.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label1.Visible = true;
            DropDownList2.Visible = true;
        }
        if (cbComputerType.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label2.Visible = true;
            DropDownList3.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbDepartment.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label2.Visible = true;
            DropDownList3.Visible = true;
        }
        if (cbRoomNumber.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label3.Visible = true;
            DropDownList4.Visible = true;
        }
        if (cbComputerPosition.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label4.Visible = true;
            DropDownList5.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbGraphicsCard.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label5.Visible = true;
            DropDownList6.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbRAM.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label6.Visible = true;
            DropDownList7.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbProgram.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label7.Visible = true;
            DropDownList8.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbInstallDate.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label8.Visible = true;
            DropDownList9.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbExperationDate.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label9.Visible = true;
            DropDownList10.Visible = true;
        }         

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cbComputerType2.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label1.Visible = true;
            DropDownList2.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbDepartment2.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label2.Visible = true;
            DropDownList3.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbRoomNumber2.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label3.Visible = true;
            DropDownList4.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbGraphicsCard2.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label5.Visible = true;
            DropDownList6.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbRAM2.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label6.Visible = true;
            DropDownList7.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbProgram2.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label7.Visible = true;
            DropDownList8.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbComputerType3.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label1.Visible = true;
            DropDownList2.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbGraphicsCard3.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label5.Visible = true;
            DropDownList6.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbRAM3.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label6.Visible = true;
            DropDownList7.Visible = true;
        }

        if (cbProgram3.Checked == true)
        {

            Panel5.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
            Label7.Visible = true;
            DropDownList8.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```